# Adding page numbers with Ghostscript

Tags: php, pdf-generation, ghostscript

For one of the projects assigned to me, I have the following problem.

I have a document generated through DOMPDF, to which is appended two existing PDFs from a list of pre-determined documents.

I use Ghostscript to assemble the entire thing into one PDF for presentation purposes, but it's been requested that I add page numbers to the whole thing.

Now, just using DOMPDF, I can add page number just to that one part of the final PDF, but that doesn't help with page numbers for the two files appended afterwards.

Currently, this is the Ghostscript command I use to assemble the documents into one PDF

```
$cmd = 'gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -o '
       .'"'.$finalFile.'" '
       .'"'.$domPdfFile.'" '
       .'"'.$appendFileOne '" '
       .'"'.$appendFileTwo.'"';
exec($cmd);
```

As I said, this works fine for assembling the various documents into the `$finalFile`. And I can add page number to the file created through DOMPDF before it gets to that command. (So, for example, I will have a 20 page document, but only pages 1-9 will have numbers.)

But I need page numbers all the way through, and since the number of pages from the `$domPdfFile` are inconsistent, I can't just put page numbers on those appended files.

Is this something that Ghostscript can do? (apply page numbers across the finished document?)

Or do I need to be looking at something else to accomplish this?

(Please do not suggest using something other than DOMPDF. I would love to move away from it, but this is legacy code I'm having to maintain, and I just can't find the time right now for another option.)

Comment: You *could* do it with Ghostscript but it would be exceedingly hard work, and **very** prone to error unless your documents are quite rigidly defined. You would need a custom EndPage procedure which draws the page number on the content, using the number of showpage operations executed so far. The problem is that if there is any variation in the document at all the page number will end up in the wrong place, or colliding with the existing content. (I'm assuming you want page numbers drawn on the canvas, rather than logical page numbering displayed by Acrobat)

Comment: The documents are largely rigidly defined. I say largely because we have a default template that the DOMPDF generated documents uses, but the appended PDFs are.... less defined, shall we say. (They're all the same page size, fortunately, but the margins aren't always consistent.)

Fortunately, it looks like I'm going to be able to get away with just page numbers on the DOMPDF generated document.

Regardless, thank you.